# Why does this Nix SQLite overlay lead to recompiling Python 3.10 packages?

Tags: nix

I created a [repository](https://github.com/cideM/nix_why_sqlite/blob/main/flake.nix) to demonstrate the problem. Clone it and run `nix develop`. This will try to enter the `devShell` which has `sqlite` as an input. That in turn is modified through an overlay that adds a compile flag:

```
(self: super:
  sqlite = super.sqlite.overrideAttrs (oldAttrs:
    configureFlags = oldAttrs.configureFlags ++ ["--enable-dynamic-extensions"];
  });
})
```

You'll now find yourself going through this:

```
[1/2/241 built] building python3.10-cffi-1.15.1
```

this goes on for quite some time seemingly re-building the entire Python ecosystem.

The [source](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-unstable/pkgs/development/libraries/sqlite/default.nix) for SQLite in the `nixpkgs` repository does reference `python3Packages` but I don't understand why this would recompile anything.

I also tried stubbing out the inputs using `sqlite.override (_: { python3Packages = {}; })` but that has no effect on the recompilation. Stubbing out something like `lib` obviously breaks the build, so it seems the `override` clause itself is in effect.

Comment: The reason is likely that the Nix Python ecosystem has many dependencies on SQLite. I was able to work around the problem by using `sqlite-interactive.override (...)` without going through an overlay. That works! Not sure if I should submit that as the accepted answer thuough since it doesn't really "solve" the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `nix why-depends --derivation nixpkgs#python3Packages.cffi nixpkgs#sqlite` (we use `--derivation` because we are concerned with build-time deps, not runtime deps):

```
/nix/store/i0h1pz3y6hn6zk5h01z2mn517gfn50h0-python3.10-cffi-1.15.1.drv
└───/nix/store/8zacqzz62px96vz3705kawrkhk3najhp-python3-3.10.12.drv
    └───/nix/store/dy3i053xjf62x8sd2yypz20cyg40mpp1-sqlite-3.42.0.drv
```

By changing sqlite, you have changed python3, and by changing python3, you have changed python3Packages.cffi.

> The source for SQLite in the nixpkgs repository does reference python3Packages … I also tried stubbing out the inputs using `sqlite.override (_: { python3Packages = {}; })`

This is irrelevant, because, as noted in [the comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/0d9d11080c4bdb9788b9c553ae9efca13ae5ac59/pkgs/development/libraries/sqlite/default.nix#L3-L4), sqlite only uses python3 for tests that are not run during build. We can confirm by following the usage of `python3Packages` and finding it is only used in `passthru`, which is not part of the build. Regardless of that, it’s still irrelevant because sqlite is only *using* `python3Packages` there, and so not altering it in any way that would cause a rebuild of `python3Packages`. I.e., you were looking at the problem (and so the dependency graph) backwards.